# MsAccess convert scientific notation

Tags: ms-access, type-conversion

I am using MsAccess and have some data that I imported from an Excelfile in a table.

How do I convert a short text field with a scientific notation into a text field with a "normal" notation?

[image]

The value should be 973185349048.

I have tried, CDbl, Val, Trim but the value is always off.

Thanks

Comment: The value gets imported as 973185349050.  The last two digits are off.

Comment: Is the data actually created in Excel, or is it a CSV file that has been opened in Excel? If the latter, try importing the original CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Import as to a (temporary) table having the data type set to Numeric, Decimal and (probably) zero decimals.

Increase the property Precision to, say, 18:

[image]

Comment: I tried this (and also other precisions), but the result is still 973185349050.

Comment: Yes, that's one of your two sample values ...

Comment: The value has to be 973185349048, NOT 973185349050.  
It's a bankaccountnumber, it has to be correct.  In the example I gave 2 times the same bankaccountnumber (as a scientific notation).

Comment: You'll see both values in the screenshot above. However, bank accounts are not numbers as such, just using digits only, and may have _leading zeroes_. Thus, these should be stored as _Text_.

Comment: I know, that's why I said I wanted to convert the scientific notation into a text field with a "normal notation".  No leading zeros in the example.

Comment: Oh, missed that, sorry. But if your text expression now is `97318534905e+11`, the trailing `48` has already been rounded to `5`, and there is no way to restore that. So, somehow you must go back to the point where you have the full numbers and redesign your retrieval to keep the values as text.

Comment: Ok ... that's a logical explanation.  So, I don't have to waste my time trying to correct it in MsAccess, it has to be correct on import. 
Preferably directly in the Excel-file (where it 's stored as a number).

Comment: Yes. The traditional method is to set up an _import specification_ when using the import wizard.

Comment: It's automated, so I don't use the import wizard.  I can't seem to find how to automate the import wizard for Excel-files.

Comment: Found it: External Data > Saved Imports
Thanks for the help @Gustav

Answer (score 0):

In the original Excel file, the `bankaccountnumber` has a data type `number`.
On import (via “External Data” > “SavedImports”), I changed it to `LongText`.
Then the format is as desired (using `<>` scientific notation).

Thanks to Gustav for the help.